# User Profiles - Merge BCS with AD Sync Data

Tags: user-profile, bcs, profile-sync, bdc

Preface: Yes, I've read many, many articles related to each aspect of this issue, but still welcome any references.

Problem: I'm unable to merge BCS (SQL connection) data with user profiles pulled in from Active Directory Synchronization (Working perfectly).

**Note: When monitoring via missclient, no records are imported**

Environment Info: 2013 On-premise with January 2016 CU

BCS Connection Info (Setup via SPD):

- External Content Type to local SQL database setup with Impersonate Windows Identity using Secure Store Application
- Read Item Operation with identity of e-mail for filter returning all columns
- Read List Operation with limit of 1000 records
- I'm able to read the items no problem via SPD and after creating a list & form via SPD

Business Data Connectivity Service App Info:

- Set Object permissions to Execute & Set Permissions for all service accounts (just to eliminate the possibility)

Secure Store Service App Info:

- Using Id in connection for secure store application id
- Type - tried both Group & Individual
- Credentials - Set to account
- Even generated a new key
- Permissions - Set to all service accounts (just to eliminate the possibility)

Comment: Have you tested the ECT as an external list and accessed it with the User Profile Connection account to ensure access?

Comment: I have and while I can access the data through the external list, I was never able to sync to the data store via the User Profile Sync process. I have since turned to using a Powershell script to merge the data. I would post the code that I used to get the SQL information and how I update the SP user profile, but it's too many characters. Just send me a private msg and I'll send it to you.

Comment: That's OK, I know how. What are you seeing in the logs during the import. I still suspect that you are having a permissions issue. Did you access the external list as the UPS connection account?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the portion of Powershell script that I used to connect directly to the SQL database, query the data and update the SP user profile:

```
if($mcpUserProfile["WorkEmail"] -ne $null)
{
 $trimEmail = $mcpUserProfile["WorkEmail"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper()

#Use sql ado connection to connect directly to sql database
$SQLServer = "ServerName\InstanceName (if applicable)"
$SQLDBName = "DatabaseName"
$SqlQuery = "select * from viewName WHERE PropertyName = '$trimEmail'" 

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = TRUE"

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$SqlConnection.Close()

#iterate through HCM data to find match based on e-mail address
foreach($item in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows) {

if ($item["Email"] -ne $null) {
$trimHcmEmail = $item["Email"].ToString().ToUpper().Trim()

if($trimHcmEmail -eq $trimEmail) {

if ($item['LocationName'] -ne $null) {
#update associated location user profile properties
$userDomainAccount["EmployeeOfficeLocation"].Value = $item['LocationName']
$userDomainAccount["SPS-Location"].Value = $item['LocationName']
$userDomainAccount["Office"].Value = $item['LocationName']
}                           
#save changes to the profile                              
$userDomainAccount.Commit()
break
} 
}
}
}
```